# error while running rake about command

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I installed everything of ruby on rails on my linux system..and then when I type the command 'rake about' the following is the error..plz help

```
   rake aborted!
   Could not find a JavaScript runtime. See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs for a                   list of available runtimes.
   /home/imobigeeks1/work/demo/jbuilder/ruby/1.8/gems/execjs-1.4.0/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb:51:in `autodetect'
   /home/imobigeeks1/work/demo/jbuilder/ruby/1.8/gems/execjs-1.4.0/lib/execjs.rb:5
   /home/imobigeeks1/work/demo/jbuilder/ruby/1.8/gems/coffee-script-2.2.0/lib/coffee_script.rb:1:in `require'
   /home/imobigeeks1/work/demo/jbuilder/ruby/1.8/gems/coffee-script-2.2.0/lib/coffee_script.rb:1
   /home/imobigeeks1/work/demo/jbuilder/ruby/1.8/gems/coffee-script-2.2.0/lib/coffee-script.rb:1:in `require'
   /home/imobigeeks1/work/demo/jbuilder/ruby/1.8/gems/coffee-script-2.2.0/lib/coffee-    script.rb:1
   /home/imobigeeks1/work/demo/jbuilder/ruby/1.8/gems/coffee-rails-3.2.2/lib/coffee-  rails.rb:1:in `require'
   /home/imobigeeks1/work/demo/jbuilder/ruby/1.8/gems/coffee-rails-3.2.2/lib/coffee-  rails.rb:1
   /home/imobigeeks1/work/demo/config/application.rb:7
   /home/imobigeeks1/work/demo/Rakefile:5
   (See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

And I also installed javascript using `gem install execjs` command still its showing the same problem

Comment: please format your post and provide the relevant code here, don't refer to repositories

Comment: did you install bundle?\

Comment: rake aborted! Could not find a JavaScript runtime.

Comment: yes i installed bundle version is 1.3.2 @ganesh kunwar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put `gem 'therubyracer'` in your gemfile and then do `bundle install` from command line.

This gem is for-

> Call JavaScript code and manipulate JavaScript objects from Ruby. Call
>   Ruby code and manipulate Ruby objects from JavaScript.

Source - http://rubydoc.info/gems/therubyracer/0.11.4/frames